# Infer generic argument when extending a Typescript interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an `interface` which requires a generic variable:

```
interface Action<T extends string> {
   type: T
}
```

I am able to extend it when I set the value of the generic:

```
interface SomeAction extends Action<"something"> {
}
```

I would like to infer the generic automatically, but I get an error when I try this:

```
interface SomeAction extends Action {
   type: "something"
}
```

> Error TS2314: Generic type 'Action' requires 1 type argument(s).

I'd like the second example to infer its type automatically. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify default value for `T` and it should work:

```
interface Action<T extends string = string> {}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iAPAFWQgA9IQATAZ2UrClAHNkBeGuxgPmQG8AoZAWACeABwgAuZPl4BfXr1CRYiFAGUsAWwjpMOIqQgVqO7CB79BoicgBElTRDAALRjdnIA9B+TksESiAA5GDIAO5YUADWyAC0aBimyFAQAI4ArsDJ1AyG0MAIyHBQDPKK0PBIyOpaJjgATPpkVPG6eHYOzq5cfDLI8gA2jgJwyJLV2gl6rHwCs8Jio+1anSAMbnK8gyEARqNVDrUgDdMWc1aL9ssuq+vyI6zbANxAA)

Comment: @Eldar Are you sure? Can you provide some examples in which such a solution wouldn't work?

Comment: Sorry, my bad to make that assumption.

Comment: @Eldar It's okay, everyone can make a wrong assumption :)